# vue router-link only works in app.vue but not in child components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my App.vue it has a child component. Why is it that `router-link` gets triggered if I have it in App.vue but not if I have it in the child component?

App.vue:

```
<router-link to = "/test">1234567</router-link>
<router-view/>
<navigation-drawer v-if="showNav && n==1"/>
```

navigationdrawer.vue:

```
<router-link to = "/test"><v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon></router-link>
```

From App.vue, when the router link is clicked, it takes me to the correct route but from the child component `navigationdrawer` the link doesn't seem to even trigger. Why is that the case?

Comment: is there any error in the console?

Comment: None at all, that's the strange part

Comment: @MarkShaio Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @MarkShaio I belive this might be just a typo, in '/test'